# Adding multiple inputs to query MS SQL Server instance using 'node-mssql' npm package

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, tedious, node-mssql

I would like to query MS SQL Server instance to serve a very simple `POST` request. I am using nodejs + express. The following code (async version) considers only first `input` types only and therefore returns error -

```
  let pool = await sql.connect(dbCredentials);
  let bookName = "string to be matched" ; 
  let ranksVal= 10
  
  let result = await pool
    .request()
    .input("item", sql.VarChar, bookName)
    .input("ranksVal", sql.Int , ranksVal)
    .query(`select top @ranksVal * from dbTable where book = @item order by counts desc`);
```

Ideally, the above code should return a result for the following SQL query :

```
 select top 10 * from dbTable where book = "string to be matched" order by counts desc
```

Alternatively, the following solution works :

```
  let result = await pool
    .request()
    .input("item", sql.VarChar, bookName)
    .query(`select top ${ranksVal} * from dbTable where book = @item order by counts desc`);
```

But I would like to understand how can we pass multiple values to `req.input()` method.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an expression or a parameter in a TOP values clause you must use parentheses.  eg

```
 .query(`select top (@ranksVal) * from dbTable where book = @item order by counts desc`);
```